How can we get the route that was navigated?
Suppose an error occurred while executing Navigator.push(...) and the application opens a page (screen) that handles and displays this error.
On the error page, how can we get the route that was navigated?
For example, the error occurred when there is no internet, and when the error page is displayed, the user turns on the internet, so you can make the button to continue (i.e. to open that route again)
Navigator.pushReplacement(
    context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const <here is the route I navigated to before the error page appeared>);

p.s. the application doesn't use named routes

if you navigate to your error page with Navigator.push why dont you call Navigator.pop() ?

@pmatatias Navigator.pop() will just display previous route but I need to reopen the route that was navigated (If I can explain it correctly)

how about passing the current page widget to your error page as an arguments. and use it on your continue button?
because you want to use pushReplaceMant which is delete all previous route.

Navigating to a different page on error is not the best approach. Let's say you have a widget, the page UserDetailsPage.
There you should have different states for the Initial state, Error state, Loaded state etc.
You should render a different state according to the state.
If for some reason you don't like this approach, the only thing you should do in your approach is to pop back to where you navigated from using Navigator.of(context).pop();
